# Are contact forces exerted due to gravity

Tags: newtonian-gravity, contact-mechanics

For example, a book rests upon a table, on earth the weight of the object is balanced by the normal reaction force exerted by the table on the book but in reality, the normal contact isn't the reaction of the weight but is present due to Pauli's exclusion principle. let's say this scenario is in deep space, with no weight acting on the table will the table still exert a contact force on the book

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is normal force due to gravity regarded as contact force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/632626/)

Comment: Voting to reopen. The linked question does not mention gravity. It describes the origin of contact forces at a quantum level i.e. why solid objects do not interpenetrate - but that is not what this questioner is asking.

Comment: There are contact forces acting between brake pads and wheels (e.g. bicycle rims or discs). Do you consider these to be gravitational?

Answer (score 0):

What we call a normal force is simply a consequence of Newton's third law of motion - if object A exerts a force on object B then B will exert an equal and opposite force on A. We call this a "normal" force because it is normal or perpendicular to the surface to which the force is applied.

One of the forces involved may be the weight of an object, as is the case in your example of a book resting on a table. But there may be other forces involved as well - for example, if we push down on the book, then the normal force increases, so it is now greater than the weight of the book. Normal forces are not necessarily vertical - if we push against a vertical wall then the normal force from the wall is horizontal. And in outer space, if A uses a rocket motor to push against B then B will exert an equal and opposite normal force on A, even though gravity is not involved at all.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question let's assume a situation: let say a book and a table are placed in free space, zero gravity and initially at seperation d.
Then the only force would be the force due to gravity, because of this force they would fall into each other and would come close with time. After some time, depending on the initial separation, both would make contact with each other and the gravity would be balanced by the electromagnetic normal reaction due to electron-electron repulsion between them and the system should come to rest.